# Error You must initialize PFFacebookUtils

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, facebook, parse-platform

When I call the following Objective C code in my app, I get an exception.

```
    [PFFacebookUtils logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions:permissions block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
    if (!user) {
        NSLog(@"Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login Failed"
                                                        message:@"The user cancelled the Facebook login."
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    } else if (user.isNew) {
        NSLog(@"User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"logInSegue" sender:sender];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"User logged in through Facebook!");
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"logInSegue" sender:sender];
    }
}];
```

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'You must initialize PFFacebookUtils with a call to +initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions'

Below is code from the AppDelegate written in Swift and I'm not too sure how to initialise what it says in the error in Swift? I'm using the latest version of Parse and also in my PodFile, I have the following pod 'ParseFacebookUtilsV4' ? Any idea, how to fix this please?

```
    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    // Enable storing and querying data from Local Datastore.
    // Remove this line if you don't want to use Local Datastore features or want to use cachePolicy.
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore()

    Parse.setApplicationId(appID, clientKey: clientKey)
    PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions)

    let granted: Bool = AppDelegate.IsNotificationPermissionGranted()
    if (granted) {
        AppDelegate.registerNotification()
    }

    //code block from starter project
    PFUser.enableAutomaticUser()

    let defaultACL = PFACL();
    // If you would like all objects to be private by default, remove this line.
    //defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true)

    PFACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, withAccessForCurrentUser:true)

    if application.applicationState != UIApplicationState.Background {
        // Track an app open here if we launch with a push, unless
        // "content_available" was used to trigger a background push (introduced in iOS 7).
        // In that case, we skip tracking here to avoid double counting the app-open.

        let preBackgroundPush = !application.respondsToSelector("backgroundRefreshStatus")
        let oldPushHandlerOnly = !self.respondsToSelector("application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:")
        var noPushPayload = false;
        if let options = launchOptions {
            noPushPayload = options[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] != nil;
        }
        if (preBackgroundPush || oldPushHandlerOnly || noPushPayload) {
            PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions)
        }
    }

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following code to AppDelegate class in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method

```
PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions(launchOptions)
```

Note that you might need to import ParseFacebookUtilsV4 first.

Comment: Thank you Ivan, I had tried that but then removed that line of code because it didn't recognise the PFFacebookUtils because silly me forgot to import ParseFacebookUtilsV4